# Обьясните пожалуйста разницу

Tags: c#

Задача: Проверить является ли заданный граф(неориентированный) регулярным(все вершины имеют одинаковую степень).
В первую строку приходит количество графов K. В вторую количество вершин N и ребер M. Дальше M строк по 2 числа - описание ребер. В конце программа должна выводить YES или NO. Так вот у меня есть 2 кода. Мой:

```
    using System;


namespace ConsoleApp26
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            string res = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                int[] nm = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(), int.Parse);
                int[] degres = new int[nm[0]];
                for (int j = 0; j < nm[1]; j++)
                {
                    int[] temp = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(), int.Parse);
                    degres[temp[0] - 1]++;
                    degres[temp[1] - 1]++;
                }
                if (RegularGraf(degres))
                {
                    res += "YES\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    res += "NO\n";
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(res);

        }

        static bool RegularGraf(int[] degres)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < degres.Length; i++)
            {
                if (degres[i] != degres[0])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

и ГПТшный:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        string res = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            string[] nm = Console.ReadLine().Split();
            int n = int.Parse(nm[0]);
            int m = int.Parse(nm[1]);
            int[] degrees = new int[n];
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                string[] edge = Console.ReadLine().Split();
                int u = int.Parse(edge[0]) - 1;
                int v = int.Parse(edge[1]) - 1;
                degrees[u]++;
                degrees[v]++;
            }
            bool isRegular = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (degrees[j] != degrees[0])
                {
                    isRegular = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            res += isRegular ? "YES\n" : "NO\n";
        }
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}
```

Разницы вроде никакой нет.
Натыкал что когда пишу `Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(), int.Parse);`, то не проходит какой-то 1 тест(посмотреть не могу). Почему так происходит?

```
using System;


namespace ConsoleApp26
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            string res = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                string[] nm = Console.ReadLine().Split();
                int n = int.Parse(nm[0]);
                int m = int.Parse(nm[1]);
                int[] degres = new int[n];
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    string[] temp = Console.ReadLine().Split();
                    degres[int.Parse(temp[0]) - 1]++;
                    degres[int.Parse(temp[1]) - 1]++;
                }
                if (RegularGraf(degres))
                {
                    res += "YES\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    res += "NO\n";
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(res);

        }

        static bool RegularGraf(int[] degres)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < degres.Length; i++)
            {
                if (degres[i] != degres[0])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Поменял

```
int[] nm = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(), int.Parse);
```

И

```
 int[] temp = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(), int.Parse);
 degres[temp[0] - 1]++;
 degres[temp[1] - 1]++;
```

На

```
string[] nm = Console.ReadLine().Split();
int n = int.Parse(nm[0]);
int m = int.Parse(nm[1]);
```

И

```
string[] temp = Console.ReadLine().Split();
degres[int.Parse(temp[0]) - 1]++;
degres[int.Parse(temp[1]) - 1]++;
```

И все работает так что не так с `Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(), int.Parse);`

Comment: Отладка в таких случаях помогает.

Comment: Каким образом? Я не знаю на каких именно наборах выводит не правильно, все что я вижу это то что один тест не проходит на моем варианте.

Comment: А я например каким образом должен это узнать?

Comment: ну ок, у вас где N и M считывается? нигде. Начните с этого.

Comment: Наверное я не правильно задал вопрос. Вопрос не в том какой тест у меня не проходит, а в том почему через Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(), int.Parse) не срабатывает, а когда я отдельно паршу массив строк все тесты проходят

Comment: я уже написал, потому что вы отдельно не считываете M и N.

Comment: int[] nm = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(), int.Parse); Вот же 0 - N, 1 - M

Comment: если бы у меня N и M не считывался у меня бы не проходил ни один тест

Comment: вижу, такой код странный, никогда так не писал

Comment: Возможно тот тест на производительность или расход памяти, а не на логику работы. Используя ConvertAll вы создаете лишний `int[]` массив, которого во втором варианте нет. Сами себя перемудрили, получается.

Comment: В ошибке написано возможные причины: деление на ноль, обращение к несуществующему элементу

Comment: программа закончилась ошибкой

Comment: Что вижу, то и пишу. Ваш код создает в 2 раза больше мусора, чем без `ConvertAll`, остальные вопросы можно задать разработчику тестов, который не может вывести нормально исключение на экран.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я могу предположить причину ошибки при использовании `Array.ConvertAll`.
Вероятно, на вход подаётся строка с пробелом в конце.

Допустим, на вход подана строка `4 5` - тогда `Console.ReadLine().Split()` вернёт массив из двух строк.
А если на вход подать строку `4 5`  - тогда `Split()` вернёт массив из трёх строк. Последняя - пустая. При этом `ConvertAll` все три попытается распарсить в `int` и на последней строке будет ошибка.

---

Метод `Split` имеет несколько перегрузок и может принимать параметр `count`, ограничивающий количество элементов в итоговом массиве.

```
Console.WriteLine("4 5".Split().Length); // 2
Console.WriteLine("4 5 ".Split().Length); // 3
Console.WriteLine("4 5 ".Split(' ', 2).Length); // 2
```

Попробуйте указать этот параметр при использовании `Array.ConvertAll` и отпишитесь, пройдут ли тесты успешно.

Comment: Походу да. Так засчитало все тесты. Спасибо большое!